# D3 curved lines reversed

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

**How can i make these lines arc the opposite way?**

I saw this post: [Curved line on d3 force directed tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13455510/curved-line-on-d3-force-directed-tree) and i found a way to make lines to the left arch the other way by switching the start position and end position. The problem appears when i want to animate things along the path.

Is there a better way i can do this without switching the start and end positions?

```
var startX, startY, endX, endY;

var line = lineGroup.insert('path')
    .attr('class', 'map__airport__line')
    .attr('id', 'line-' + self.attr('id') + '-' + target.attr('id'))
    .attr('d', function() {
        if (parseInt(target.attr('cx')) > parseInt(self.attr('cx'))) {
            startX = self.attr('cx');
            startY = self.attr('cy');
            endX   = target.attr('cx');
            endY   = target.attr('cy');
        } else {
            startX = target.attr('cx');
            startY = target.attr('cy');
            endX   = self.attr('cx');
            endY   = self.attr('cy');
        }

        var dx   = target.attr('cx') - self.attr('cx'),
            dy   = target.attr('cy') - self.attr('cy'),
            dr   = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy),
            path =
                'M' + startX + "," + startY +
                'A' + dr + ',' + dr + ' 0 0,1 ' +
                endX + ',' + endY;

        return path;
    });
```

Comment: switching the start and end positions is easiest. You could apply a transform to mirror the arc but that seems more complicated to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the 0 0,1 to 0 0 0:

```
var startX, startY, endX, endY;

var line = lineGroup.insert('path')
.attr('class', 'map__airport__line')
.attr('id', 'line-' + self.attr('id') + '-' + target.attr('id'))
.attr('d', function() {
    if (parseInt(target.attr('cx')) > parseInt(self.attr('cx'))) {
        startX = self.attr('cx');
        startY = self.attr('cy');
        endX   = target.attr('cx');
        endY   = target.attr('cy');
    } else {
        startX = target.attr('cx');
        startY = target.attr('cy');
        endX   = self.attr('cx');
        endY   = self.attr('cy');
    }

    var dx   = target.attr('cx') - self.attr('cx'),
        dy   = target.attr('cy') - self.attr('cy'),
        dr   = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy),
        path =
            'M' + startX + "," + startY +
            'A' + dr + ',' + dr + ' 0 0 0 ' +
            endX + ',' + endY;

    return path;
});
```

See the documentation on arc paths here:
[enter link description here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths#Arcs)